# Grails controller scaffold default view not displaying the data in the controller

Tags: grails

I have created several controllers in my Grails project and put data for each controller in the bootstrap, but the data does not appear in the table for each controller that scaffold provides as the default view. I have checked inside dbconsole to be certain that the data is there, which it is. I have also refreshed the dependencies to make certain that the version of the scaffolding plugin is not corrupted. I am using Grails 2.3.5 and Scaffolding 2.0.1.Are there any suggestions of what could be wrong?

```
class DepartmentController {
    static scaffold=Department

    def index() { }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a copy of one or your scaffolded controllers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking back at other examples of using scaffolding I realize now that I should have taken out the index portion of the code, even though it is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Remove your the `index` method and make it like this:

```
class DepartmentController {
    static scaffold=Department

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put some log messages into the controllers (or debug the app) right after the controller loads the data using the domain class in order to see if the query has resulted in any domain instances.

If not, activate sql logging and check the exact select statement executed. Possibly you have something wrong in your domain mapping so a wrong select stmt is sent to the db